# How to take screen shot with some settings in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Is there anyway to take screenshots of all test cases run using eclipse ? Is there any setting which needs to be done ?
Please help if it is possible

Thanks
Rubi

Comment: What do you mean by a *screenshot*?

Answer (score 0):

No, Eclipse does not provide any screenshot capability itself. That would be up to a utility/application on your OS.